# A safer way to cut a string

Tags: strings, functional-programming, scala, exception-handling

I want to get just the first line of a big string. Currently, here's how I do it:

```
def getFirstParagraph(txt: String) = {
    val newLineIdx = txt.indexOf("\n") match {
        case i: Int if i > 0 => i
        case _               => txt.length
    }

    txt.substring(0, newLineIdx)
}
```

But my friend sees some downfall: if `txt` is `null`, there will be an exception. His suggestion involved using `var`:

```
def getFirstParagraph(txt: String) = {
    var result = txt
    scala.util.control.Exception.ignoring(classOf[Exception]) {
        result = result.substring(0, result.indexOf("\n"))
    }
    result
}
```

Which will handle the `null` value fine. Thing is, I'm quite uncomfortable using `var`. How can I handle this case without using `var` (aka the Scala / functional way)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
scala> def getFirstParagraph(txt: String) = {
         Option(txt).map(_.takeWhile(c => c != '\n')).orNull
       }
getFirstParagraph: (txt: String)String

scala> getFirstParagraph(null)
res2: String = null

scala> getFirstParagraph("fsdfasf")
res3: String = fsdfasf

scala> getFirstParagraph("fsdfasf\nxxxxxxx")
res4: String = fsdfasf
```

`Option(txt)` converts `txt` into an `Option[String]` which will be `None` if `txt` is null.

`map` will execute the `takeWhile` only if the `Option` is `Some`.

Finally `orNull` will pull the value out of the `Option` if it is `Some` or evaluate to `null` otherwise.

Comment: This gives me a warning: "<console>:9: warning: comparing values of types Char and java.lang.String using `!=' will always yield true" on Sacla 2.9.2, also the code didn't work...

Comment: Nevermind, silly mistake. I tested against `"\n"`, not `'\n'`. Sorry.

Answer (score 12):

Here's my take on it:

```
def getFirstParagraph(txt: String): String = txt.lines.next
```

As to the `null` objection: in idiomatic Scala, you don't use `null`. If there's some API which might return you a `null` string, then, *at that point*, you turn it into an `Option`, and handle the `Option` elsewhere as needed.

Handling `null` (or even `Option`) at the `getFirstParagraph` method is misplaced.

Comment: I agree on the misplaced responsabilities note.

Comment: Good point, I agree.

Answer (score 5):

ericacm's code may be shortened (removing explicit lambda notation). Also, propagating `null` is a bad/dangerous thing (unless you are forced to stay close to the metal, but then how about writing in C), so why not return an `Option`?

```
def getFirstParagraph(txt: String) = {
    Option(txt).map(_.takeWhile(_ != '\n'))
}
```

Or, if you don't use this from Java, testing for `null` is kinda weird, as in pure world there is no `null`. So there is:

```
def getFirstParagraph(txt: String) = {
    txt.takeWhile(_ != '\n')
}
```

Comment: In the second case map call is excess.